# C++ reference variable clarification

Tags: c++, variables, reference

I think most would be surprised about the topic again, However I am referring to a book "C++ Common Knowledge: Essential Intermediate Programming" written by "Stephen C. Dewhurst".

In the book, he quotes a particular sentence (in section under Item 5. References Are Aliases, Not Pointers), which is as below

> A reference is an alias for an object that already exists prior to the initialization of the reference. Once a reference is initialized to refer to a particular object, **it cannot later be made to refer to a different object**; a reference is bound to its initializer for its whole lifetime

Can anyone please explain the context of **"cannot later be made to refer to a different object"**

Below code works for me,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int i = 100;
 int& ref = i;
 cout<<ref<<endl;

 int k = 2000;
 ref = k;
 cout<<ref<<endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Here I am referring the variable `ref` to both `i` and `j` variable.
And the code works perfectly fine.

Am I missing something?  I have used SUSE10 64bit linux for testing my sample program.

Thanks for your input in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You aren't binding `ref` to another object: when you do `ref = k`, it is as though you did `i = k`, which simply reassigned *the value of* `i`.  In other words, you're calling `i`'s `operator=`.

Here's something that better demonstrates the idea:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ostream& stream = std::cout;
    stream = std::cerr; // fails to compile!  Cannot access ostream::operator=
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The line `ref = k` is not changing what `ref` is referring to, it is assigning the value of `k` to the value of `ref`. If you subsequently print `i` you will find that `i` is now 2000 as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 100;
    int& ref = i;
    int k = 2000;
    ref = k;

    if (&ref == &i) std::cout << "ref is bound to i\n";
    if (&ref == &k) std::cout << "ref is bound to k\n";
}
```